# Pattern matching within an inOrder function

Tags: design-patterns, haskell, pattern-matching, matching

I've just started Haskell programming, and never used a functional language before.

I'm trying to write a function, using pattern matching, that will test if a given integer list is in ascending order. It should return true if it is, and false if it isn't.

```
inorder :: [Integer] -> Bool
inorder [] = True
inorder [x] = True
inorder (x:y:t) | x<=y && y<=head t = True
        | otherwise = False
```

This currently only compares the first two elements of a given list.

**Q1 How would I go about comparing every integer to the one ahead of it, when there is one ahead of it in the list?**

This is homework, and I'm suppose to do it using pattern matching, not guarded equations, but I've had to use both as I'm not sure what the pattern matching equivalent of "otherwise" is.

**Q2 Is it possible, and how would I go about writing this function without guards?**

Thanks for taking the time to read. I apologise if anything is unclear.
Any help, tips or helpful links are appreciated.

Comment: It can make sense to declare (x:y:t) as the first pattern. Then you only need `inorder _ = True` to match the rest of the cases. What this buys you, is a single pattern matching (match `x:y:t`, or proceed), vs _three_ patterns matched. Although this order may at first feel "wrong".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Q1.* Use recursion. You compare the first two values, and then do the same for the remaining list, where the second value is still included, so it gets compared to the 3rd of the orginal list:

```
inorder (x:y:t)
  | x <= y && inorder (y:t) = True -- We included y in the call to inorder
  | otherwise = False
```

*Q2.* Yes, that is possible. Observe that in the previous function, we returned True when a given term was True and False otherwise. This means that we can just return the value of the term, instead of using guards:

```
inorder (x:y:t) = x <= y && inorder (y:t)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a recursive call:

```
inorder (x:y:t) | x<=y = inorder (y:t)
                | otherwise = False
```

Why do you want to write without guards?

Comment: It's one of many tasks that were set by my lecturer to be solved using pattern matching. Thanks for the prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

You're on your way to the answer that you would almost certainly want to turn in for a class assignment. But I want to suggest another approach that is closer to the kind of thing you would want to do in production code: namely, write the little bit of domain-specific logic yourself but reuse existing higher-order functions for the recursion logic. In such a small example, it's hard to see the benefit; but getting used to this kind of separation of concerns helps a lot with big engineering projects. Here's an example of how that would look.

```
-- this is the domain-specific logic
frontInOrder (x:y:_) = x <= y
frontInOrder _ = True

-- here we do the recursion by handing the list off to tails/all
inOrder = all frontInOrder . tails
```

Of course, `frontInOrder` itself can be bikeshedded quite a lot. You might think about something like this, for example, where there's not even any pattern matching:

```
sorted xs = sort xs == xs
frontInOrder = sorted . take 2
inOrder = all frontInOrder . tails
```

Or you could even consider just `inOrder xs = sort xs == xs` with no other auxiliary functions if the difference between linear time and linearithmic time is not too important for your application. (The advantage you get by paying this logarithmic runtime cost is that this code is very short -- and it's hard to hide bugs in short code!)

Again, I'm not suggesting doing this kind of thing in your exercise solutions: to begin with, you absolutely should write a couple hundred functions manually. But once you start spotting some patterns, you just as absolutely should look for opportunities for code reuse.